# MySQL _ Retrieve multiple rows and columns in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

am new to Mysql

I want to retrieve all the columns containing StrainName=M18 from the database , but am getting error. please help me in this

```
SELECT * 

strain.strainName,
feature.contigId,
feature.startPosition,
feature.stopPosition,
feature.orfId,
feature.orfType,
feature.funcClassification,
feature.rastId,
feature.strand 
from feature,strain 
where feature.id=strain.id and strainName='M18';
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'strain.strainName,feature.contigId,feature.startPosition,feature.stopPosition,fe' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

you need add comma after `*`

```
SELECT  *,                      -- <<====== HERE
        strain.strainName,
        feature.contigId,
        feature.startPosition,
        feature.stopPosition,
        feature.orfId,
        feature.orfType,
        feature.funcClassification,
        feature.rastId,
        feature.strand 
from    feature,strain 
where   feature.id=strain.id and 
        strainName='M18';
```

Comment: what does that mean? Select all columns and repeat these columns again? I never saw the star used with column names before. Thanks

Comment: @Saher this answer only illustrates where the error is. Maybe the OP want to try something. even the user use `*` and selects the columns, itthose duplicate columns will not be shown on the list.

Comment: @Scotch what do you mean valid? it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @jw I was asking because I haven't used that syntax. You select all `*`, then specific columns from both tables and "join" in the where clause rather than selecting the columns and joining the tables. I wasn't claiming it is invalid, it's just different and I was wondering what it does differently.

Comment: Valid, yes. Makes sense, no.

Answer (score 1):

to get all columns:

```
SELECT * from feature,strain 
where feature.id=strain.id and strainName='M18';
```

to get specific columns :

```
SELECT                       
        strain.strainName,
        feature.contigId,
        feature.startPosition,
        feature.stopPosition,
        feature.orfId,
        feature.orfType,
        feature.funcClassification,
        feature.rastId,
        feature.strand 
from    feature,strain 
where   feature.id=strain.id and 
        strainName='M18';
```